# In C how do I "reverse" this operator |=

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm new to programming in C and I have the following situation where I know what needs to be done, I'm just not sure of the right way to do. I'll try to keep it as simple as possible, and please let me know if I'm not providing enough info.

There's a .h file with this line:

```
#define NS_CONN_ENTITYTOOLARGE    0x2000
```

Then in the C code we have the following flag being set:

```
connPtr->flags |= NS_CONN_ENTITYTOOLARGE;
```

Then later on this test:

```
if (connPtr->flags & NS_CONN_ENTITYTOOLARGE) {
}
```

Now what I want to do is basically "undo" the flag `NS_CONN_ENTITYTOOLARGE`. After some Googling I discovered that `|=` is a "bitwise OR", but I don't feel a lot more enlightened after learning that. Do I need to do a bitwise XOR, a NOT or what?

Here are all the possible values for flags that I can find in the header file.

```
#define NS_CONN_CLOSED        0x1
#define NS_CONN_SKIPHDRS      0x2
#define NS_CONN_SKIPBODY      0x4
#define NS_CONN_READHDRS      0x8
#define NS_CONN_SENTHDRS      0x10
#define NS_CONN_KEEPALIVE     0x20
#define NS_CONN_WRITE_ENCODED     0x40
#define NS_CONN_FILECONTENT       0x80
#define NS_CONN_RUNNING           0x100
#define NS_CONN_OVERFLOW      0x200
#define NS_CONN_TIMEOUT           0x400
#define NS_CONN_GZIP          0x800
#define NS_CONN_CHUNK         0x1000
#define NS_CONN_ENTITYTOOLARGE    0x2000
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
connPtr->flags &= ~NS_CONN_ENTITYTOOLARGE;
```

This doesn't exactly "undo" `|=` because it may have been a no-op for some or all of the bits in `NS_CONN_ENTITYTOOLARGE`, if they were already in the variable. In these case, those bits will be cleared too regardless of whether they were there in the first place.

Comment: I don't understand the no-op stuff you mention. As regards what you said about it not exactly undoing, I've added all possible flag values to the question - does that help to clarify where it will undo or not?

Comment: @Brian Fenton - if all of the bits in the variable `connPtr->flags` that correspond to the bits defined in `NS_CONN_ENTITYTOOLARGE` were already set before the `|=` line was executed then effectively nothing was done (a no-op or no operation).  In this case, `&= ~` will clear the bits defined in `NS_CONN_ENTITYTOOLARGE` which leaves `connPtr->flags` with a different value than what it had originally.   This, of course, is not an "undo".

Comment: @semaj - thanks very much for explaining. If I understand you correctly, the only way "all of the bits in the variable connPtr->flags that correspond to the bits defined in NS_CONN_ENTITYTOOLARGE were already set before the |= line was executed" could occur is if NS_CONN_ENTITYTOOLARGE had been set at an earlier point. Is that right? If that's the case, then the undo would be fine (whether it sets it back to the original or not).

Comment: In general this all seems a bit odd to me, as I thought the entire purpose of these flags was to be able to easily check and set if something was true or false. I thought they were comparable to booleans in that regard, but I guess not...

Comment: @Brian - The problem is your use of the word "undo", which means restore a previous state. With Boolean values you can set or clear a value, but you don't know the previous value.

Answer (score 13):

You cannot reverse an OR to the previous value. Information is lost, consider this truth table:

```
A|B|OR
------
0|0|0
0|1|1
1|0|1
1|1|1
```

As you can see, information is lost because there are no distinct values for when A were 0 or 1.

What you want to know is how to **remove a flag**. This can be done by AND'ing with the inverse of the flag:

```
connPtr->flags &= ~NS_CONN_ENTITYTOOLARGE;
```

Comment: Thanks @nightcracker. So by removing the flag, does that affect any other flags that may have been set?

Comment: @Brian Fenton: If the flag is of the form `0x000100` not, but for example this will: `0x010010`.

Comment: sorry if my questions seem stupid, but I'm still trying to understand. In my question I gave all the possible flag values e.g. NS_CONN_ENTITYTOOLARGE is 0x2000. Neither of the values are in my question.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say "neither of the values in your coment are mentioned in my question."

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. When I said `0x` I actually meant binary. `0x2000` is 8192 in decimal. This is 2^13 exactly so this means there is only bit set to `1`. So only one flag will be set, because there is only one 1.

Answer (score 3):

A XOR:

```
connPtr->flags ^= NS_CONN_ENTITYTOOLARGE
```

---

Of course, that's considering (say):

1. `flags` = `01001101`
2. `NS_CONN` = `00010000`

Example:

```
flags |= NS_CONN;

OR 01001101
   00010000
------------
   01011101
```

And then:

```
flags ^= NS_CONN

XOR 01011101
    00010000
-------------
    01001101 (== original flags)
```

Comment: +1 Note: Make sure the bit is set; otherwise this won't do what you expect.

Comment: @Aaron Digulla sure, should have included that but I think it's implicitly known…

Comment: Now, I'm confused! Every other says to &= ~NS_CONN_ENTITYTOOLARGE. Why do you think your answer is right over that? Thanks for answering by the way!

Comment: @Brian: `^= NS_CONN_ENTITYTOOLARGE` flips the bit, `|= NS_CONN_ENTITYTOOLARGE` sets the bit, `&= ~NS_CONN_ENTITYTOOLARGE` clears the bit. Since you can't recover the original value of the bit before it was cleared, take your pick as to whether "clear this bit", or "flip this bit" best expresses what you mean by "reverse" the operation. Provided the bit is set before you do it, the result is the same.

Comment: Thanks @Steve Jessop. @Brian Fenton, try doing (or organizing) these other operations like I did, as an exercise, and check what really happens in each case. Then it's just a matter of deciding which one fits better for your case, as Steve explained.

Comment: @Brian Fenton and did you see? I even got a down vote for being the different. :-)

Comment: Thanks @Steve Jessop and @sidyll (and sidyll I'm really glad you gave a different answer - nothing like a bit of controversy to get everybody thinking!). So I see that I need to figure out whether I want to clear or flip the bit. Great...unfortunately I have no idea...

Comment: Thanks @Brian Fenton. That won't be difficult, depending on your context. But I really encourage you to search about bit fields, they can be much more readable (and understandable) than bitwise operations specially if you're at the beginning. Of course, that's might not be possible unless you want to spend some time rewriting code or waiting the next moment to use. I'll provide an example if you want, just in case.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a bitwise and with the inverse of the flag:

```
connPtr->flags &= ~NS_CONN_ENTITYTOOLARGE;
```

Every bit of `~NS_CONN_ENTITYTOOLARGE` is `1` except for the bit that it represents.
Thus, every other bit of the value gets `AND`ed with `1`, which does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't undo it per se - after the operation, `connPtr->flags` will have a 1 bit in all positions where `NS_CONN_ENTITYTOOLARGE` had a 1 bit (which is only one position in this case), and it is impossible to know what the original bit values there unless you have actually stored the original value of `connPtr->flags` somewhere. If you are interested in turning changing the bit position(s) to 0 (which may not have been the original bit value), you can do as the other posts here say.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, if you look at the list of possible values for flags, would you agree that only NS_CONN_ENTITYTOOLARGE is the only one that will affect that bit position. So in this case, you can undo the operation ie. flip or clear the bit has the same effect. Do I have it right?

Comment: @Brian Fenton: Since these constants are supposed to be used as bit flags, each of them will indeed only have one bit set to 1, and they will all have the 1 bit in different positions. As everyone else has said, `connPtr->flags &= ~NS_CONN_ENTITYTOOLARGE` will set the bit at that particular position to 0, so in a sense, that is the opposite of `connPtr->flags |= NS_CONN_ENTITYTOOLARGE`, which sets that bit to 1. (Cont.)

Comment: @Brian Fenton: (Cont.) My point is just that `connPtr->flags |= NS_CONN_ENTITYTOOLARGE` followed by `connPtr->flags &= ~NS_CONN_ENTITYTOOLARGE` will _not_ (in general) guarantee that `connPtr->flags` gets its original value back, because the bit in question could initially have been 1 (in which case `|=` will not change the value at all, and `&= ~` will change it to 0, which is not the original value). So the answer depends on what you mean by "undo". `&= ~` does "the opposite" of what `|=` does (the first sets a bit to 0, the second sets it to 1), but `a |= b; a &= ~b;` might change `a`.

Comment: +1 Great responses - thank you! I wish I could accept more than 1 answer. :-D

Answer (score 0):

To remove the flag, you use AND:

```
connPtr->flags &= ~NS_CONN_ENTITYTOOLARGE;
```

This will take all the bits in the flags *except* NS_CONN_ENTITYTOOLARGE.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `connPtr->flags &= ~NS_CONN_ENTITYTOOLARGE` where `&` is AND and `~` is NOT.